# load tensorflow CUDNNRNNRelu checkpoints for cpu inference

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently training a bidirectional RNN model using the CudnnRNNRelu on tensorflow. I want to use these checkpoints for inference on a CPU machine. The documentation suggests that models trained with Cudnn specific cells (CudnnRNNRelu, CudnnRNNTanh, CudnnLSTM etc ..) cannot be restored directly using platform independent rnn cells ( tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell etc.. ). While there are separate cells to restore LSTM and GRU cells ( CudnnComaptibleLSTMCell and CudnnCompatibleGRUCell) , there is no indication of how to use CudnnRNNRelu trained checkpoints with platform independent rnn cells.

Restoring works properly on a GPU machine. Is there a way to restore the CudnnRNNRelu checkpoints?